# can more than two arrows point towards the same state from other states in a DFA?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

Is something like this possible:

You have state A,B,C all pointing towards accepting state D.
Is this allowed?
Where online can I find a list of rules that define how an automata must be drawn or conceived?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is allowed (and in fact, you lose a lot of computational power without it)

[here is a definition of DFA (both formal and as drawings) + an example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/automata_theory/deterministic_finite_automaton.htm)

Answer (score 0):

A deterministic finite automaton is a tuple $\langle Q,\Sigma,q_0,\delta,F \rangle$, where $Q$ is a finite set ("states"), $\Sigma$ is a finite non-empty set ("alphabet"), $q_0$ is an element of $Q$ ("initial state"), $\delta$ is a function from $Q,\Sigma$ to $Q$ ("transition function"), and $F$ is a subset of $Q$ ("accepting states").

(Your definition might allow $\delta$ to be a partial function.)

As you can see, there are absolutely no constraints on the transition function, other than it being a function (or a partial function, if that is the definition you use).

In mathematics, definitions are precise. There is nothing which is left "implies" or "winked". If it's not in the definition, we don't require it. Whatever conforms to the definition, is allowed.